# Why QProcess::readAllStandardOutput reads NOT ALL output channel?

Tags: c++, qt, file-io, process, widget

I want to add output from *top* linux tool to the QTextEdit. Output from *top* is very large - may be it's reason for why this code:

```
m_pprocess = new QProcess();
m_pprocess->setCurrentWriteChannel(QProcess::StandardOutput);
m_pprocess->start("top -b -d 5.0");

connect(m_pprocess, &QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput, [this](){

    m_ptexteditProcesses->clear();
    QThread::msleep(1000);
    QByteArray ba = m_pprocess->readAllStandardOutput();
    m_ptexteditProcesses->append(ba);
    qDebug() << ba.size();
    m_ptexteditProcesses->verticalScrollBar()->triggerAction(QScrollBar::SliderToMinimum);
});
```

behave the next manner:

1. Despite of update period for the *top* command 5 seconds, my
   QTextEdit updates twice with period 1 second and waiting remained 3 - 4 seconds for next *top* update. Thats why I add `QThread::msleep(1000);` - just to see this blinking in QTextEdit
   and recognize thats data writing entirely (if summarize all
   transaction in 5 second period).
2. `qDebug()` show me next picture (1'st number -> [1 sec] -> 2'nd number -> [3 sec] -> 4'th number -> [1 sec] -> ...):

[image: QByteBuffer size]

It looks like `readAllStandardOutput();` reads not all standard output but 4096 bytes, and only then reads remained bytes (which is about 14000 i.e. there are no some read buffer limit)!

So I can't show entire output of *top* command in my QTextEdit :) Please help me do this!

**UPDATE:**

The adding `m_pprocess->waitForReadyRead(1);` can be little fix like

```
connect(m_pprocess, &QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput, [this](){

    m_ptexteditProcesses->clear();
    //QThread::msleep(1000);
    QByteArray ba;
    m_pprocess->waitForReadyRead(1);
    ba.append(m_pprocess->readAllStandardOutput());
    m_ptexteditProcesses->append(ba);
    qDebug() << ba.size();
    m_ptexteditProcesses->verticalScrollBar()->triggerAction(QScrollBar::SliderToMinimum);
});
```

And produce this new one

[image]

but is there more elegant solution that allow read standard output in single step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to make the "top" command run once and when the command is finished reading all the information, and to read it every T seconds then a QTimer can be used:

```cpp
m_pprocess = new QProcess();
m_pprocess->setCurrentWriteChannel(QProcess::StandardOutput);
m_pprocess->setProgram("top");
m_pprocess->setArguments({"-bn1"});

m_ptimer = new QTimer;
m_ptimer->setSingleShot(true);
m_ptimer->setInterval(5000);
connect(m_ptimer, &QTimer::timeout, m_pprocess, [this]{
    m_pprocess->start();
});

connect(m_pprocess, QOverload<int, QProcess::ExitStatus>::of(&QProcess::finished), [this](){
    m_ptexteditProcesses->clear();
    QByteArray ba = m_pprocess->readAllStandardOutput();
    m_ptexteditProcesses->append(ba);
    qDebug() << ba.size();
    m_ptexteditProcesses->verticalScrollBar()->triggerAction(QScrollBar::SliderToMinimum);
    m_ptimer->start();
});

m_pprocess->start();
```

Comment: I think that this can be called a solution to the problem, albeit a little stretch. The advantage of this approach is that in the slot that processes the finished () signal, you can parse the output of the top command, and only then call the top command again.